# Spring 404 error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to run spring application, but i am getting the 404 error. Can anyone please help?
I take this code from mkyong site. The example he given is working but i tried to do everything from scratch it is not working.

```
package com.mkyong.common.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;    
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World");
        return "hello";

    }

}

hello.jsp
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Message : ${message}</h1>   
</body>
</html>

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.common.controller" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>

web.xml
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Could add the log message (since start until a 404 request)?

Answer (score 0):

Add a * to the servlet's URL pattern in your web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Its not working. I created a maven project and all the codes i copy and pasted from the working example. But this also not helping.

Comment: What URI did you type into your browser and what is the context path of your servlet?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/, /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml. I have index.jsp, which will forward to the welcome page, <jsp:forward page="/welcome"></jsp:forward>

Comment: So I'm guessing "/SpringMVC" is the context path. Your Controller has a request mapping for "/welcome". Try http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/welcome.

Comment: I think i have done mistake in the maven project structure. I created the dynamic web project, and put these codes it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

use @RequestMapping("/welcome") on your method instead of class