# root mapping in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have created a spring MVC project using maven and imported it in eclipse. And mapped "/ " to controller.But whenver i run porjectit given error 404 WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/MyProject/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

My config are : 
 web.xml

```
<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
                  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
</listener>
```

HelloController.java:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World");
        return "hello";

    }

}
```

and mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.common.controller" />
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now if i change requestmapping to "/welcome" and then call url with /welcome it works. So why only for root this is not working

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21071686/1013501

Comment: nope there was no solution for this , user just created a dynamic project and copied files, But what is wrong with maven project?

Comment: For one, get rid of your `ContextLoaderListener`. It serves absolutely no purpose right now, except duplicating your beans.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis agreed. But that wont solved my issue related to root mapping